# Basic technical things about simplicial sets to have a good understanding of quasicategories

Tags: simplicial-stuff, simplicial-categories, simplicial-presheaves

May someone provide me the list of basic techniques about simplicial sets, in order to have a good understanding of the definition of a quasicategories, $\infty$-topos, $\infty$-stacks, $\infty$-moduli stacks, $\infty$-operads, like in the books of Jacob Lurie ? I know very well what is the small category Delta, and I know that presheaves on it are simplicial sets ... but I need techniques behind these simplicial approach of higher structures. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

Simplicial sets are absolutely fundamental to the study of quasi-categories. There's no easy list of things you have to know and other things you don't have to know. Therefore, you should try to gain a strong overall working knowledge of simplicial sets.

I recommend reading the survey by Curtis. It's a great introduction to simplicial sets. If things are still unclear, I found Chapter 3 of Hovey's book to be very useful. Then of course there's the book by Goerss and Jardine, though I've found this is better approached once you already have some background. It may take a while to work through these sources, but it will pay off.

Comment: I know these books very well : They probably give what I am looking for. But am I obliged to read it for what I am looking for : I know that reading these books could be helpful ... but if I come in this site, is with the hope that someone may provide me the MAIN list of techniques to build higher things à la Jacob Lurie ...

Comment: Anyway, thank you David for trying to help me !